# Theming in WordPress multisite

Tags: wordpress

I created a WordPress multi site in sub directories. When I selected a theme for a site, it is effecting on all sites in that network, but I need different themes for different sites.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the theme in the Network Admin? If so, that will be why it's being set across the whole network. You'll need to select the specific site from the Sites dropdown in the Network Admin then set the theme from that site's specific admin area.